# How does Sequoia allow unprivileged users to get root if it requires mounting a filesystem?

Tags: linux, vulnerability, file-system

[CVE-2021-33909 AKA "Sequoia"](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-33909) is a vulnerability against the filesystem code within the Linux kernel. According to [the description of the vulnerability from Qualys](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2021/07/20/sequoia-a-local-privilege-escalation-vulnerability-in-linuxs-filesystem-layer-cve-2021-33909)

> Successful exploitation of this vulnerability allows any unprivileged user to gain root privileges on the vulnerable host
>
> [...]
>
> As a result, if an unprivileged local attacker creates, mounts, and deletes a deep directory structure whose total path length exceeds 1GB, and if the attacker open()s and read()s /proc/self/mountinfo, then

I am trying to understand how this works, because in my experience an *unprivileged* user cannot *mount* anything, unless there's a mountpoint in `/etc/fstab` which has the `user` attribute set.

<del>Some people are talking about FUSE, but I believe even for FUSE, root access is needed to actually mount the filesystem just the filesystem *code* runs in user space, not kernel space.</del> (I simply lacked the knowledge that FUSE has `fusermount`, oops)

I tried The POC exploit code and it does not work for me, so... What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [advisory](https://www.qualys.com/2021/07/20/cve-2021-33909/sequoia-local-privilege-escalation-linux.txt)

> 1/ We mkdir() a deep directory structure (roughly 1M nested
> directories) whose total path length exceeds 1GB, we bind-mount it in
> an unprivileged user namespace, and rmdir() it.

If the system is configured as such, an unprivileged user could use namespaces to perform this attack.

> Set /proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone to 0, to prevent an
> attacker from mounting a long directory in a user namespace. However,
> the attacker may mount a long directory via FUSE instead

Perhaps you already have this option disabled; some distros historically have shipped with it disabled. Lacking this option will prevent the PoC from working, so maybe this is why it doesn't work for you?

> Even for fuse, root access is needed to actually mount the filesystem

From [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/fuse.html):

> One of the most important features of FUSE is allowing secure,
> non-privileged mounts

> How do non-privileged mounts work? Since the mount() system call is a
> privileged operation, a helper program (fusermount) is needed, which
> is installed setuid root.

Mounting filesystems as an unprivileged user is absolutely possible with FUSE, assuming an administrator has installed the necessary helper program.

Comment: That perfectly answers my question, thank you! Yes, in the systems I checked `/proc/sys/kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone` does not even exist  and I clearly lack enough experience with FUSE (having used it only a handful of times)

Comment: @Josh check out `sshfs`, which uses FUSE. Very handy!